# SQL inserting empty records in database - using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data gathered from a form filled out on my website, and storing that data in a database on phpMyAdmin.

Everything is working correctly, I am getting the message "Connected to Database." and "Records Inserted Successfully!", meaning that the communication between the website and the database is working.
However, when I check the database, there are empty records (the records are being inserted, but there are no values).

Not sure if this might help, but the parameters for the function 'db' say "unused".

```
    var name = request.body.FirstName;
    var surname = request.body.LastName;
    var email  = request.body.Email;
    var message  = request.body.Message;
    console.log(name + " " + surname);
    console.log(email);     console.log(message); 
    var emailMessage = "New message from " + name + " " + surname + "(" + email + ") " + message;

    function mail(emailMessage){
 var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
 user: 'XXX', // add your username
 pass: 'XXX' // add your password
 }
 });
 var mailOptions = {
 from: 'XXX', // add sender email (your email)
 to: 'XXX', // add recipient email (maybe a friend)
 subject: 'Message from Node.js app',
 html: '<p>' + emailMessage + '</p>'
 };
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
 if (error) {
 console.log(error);
 } else {
 console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
 }
 });



 }
  mail(emailMessage);



function db(name, surname, email, message){
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'db4free.net',
        user: 'XXX',
        password: 'XXX',
        database: 'feedback_db'
    });

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to Database.");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO messages (Name, Surname, Email, Message) VALUES (name, surname, email, message)";

  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("Records Inserted Successfully!");
  });
}); }


db(name, surname, email, message);

  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html'); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't evaluated inside strings. When you put `VALUES (name, surname, email, message)` in the query, it doesn't use the variables. You should put placeholders there, and supply the values as a parameter.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO messages (Name, Surname, Email, Message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

connection.query(sql, [name, surname, email, message], function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("Records Inserted Successfully!");
});
```

I can't explain why you're getting empty records -- you should be getting an error due to the invalid values in the query.

Comment: This code worked! Thank you so much, that must've been the reason that it was inserting empty records, because after using placeholders and supplying the values, the data was saved into the database and empty records are not being inserted anymore - thanks so much for your help!